# Centering <video> issue

Tags: html, css, video, centering

I use this way:

```html
.centr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The site is like this:
[image]

*The problem is picture in picture, it is not in place*

Comment: What does the (relevant) HTML look like?

Comment: We don't need tags in the title; we have them in the Tags area.

Comment: transform doesnt need a prefix. its supported by every browser. however its the worst method of centering with all the options you have (flex, auto margin, grid...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of centering a `<video>` element inside a parent div is using a flexbox:

```css
.container {
  /* just styling, nothing important */
  background-color: gray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;

  /* note these lines below */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make auto margin work, the center class must have a width:

```
.center { 
margin: 0 auto;
 width: 400px;
 }
```

Then, rather than a container, I'd apply the center class to the video itself:

```
<video class='center'>

</video>
```